# Происхождение выражения "тронуться умом"

Tags: фразеология

Интересно, а почему "сойти с ума" — это "тронуться умом"? Откуда взялось такое выражение?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так сложилось, что семантика сумасшествия в русском языке такая, что ум стоял на своём месте, а потом куда-то сошёл, спрыгнул, поехал и пр. Тронулся умом выражение того же порядка. *Лёд тронулся* и ум тоже тронулся, пришёл в движение и тем самым перестал быть вместе с человеком.

Comment: И крыша поехала))))

Answer (score 0):

смысл в том, что ум перестал находиться в своём нормальном состоянии и сместился от нормы на определенное расстояние)))(измеряемое, естественно не в метрах....))))и стал ненормальным.