# Каково происхождение метафоры «схождения» с ума?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, метафора

Нигде нет этимологии слова «сумасшедший» или фразеологизма «сойти с ума».

Почему с ума именно «сходят»?

В Википедии сказано:

> «Сумасшествие» является более современным вариантом понятия «безумие»
> и означает дословно: сошедший с ума…

Однако в словаре Макса Фасмера в статье о слове "бред" пишется:

> ...Миклошич... и Бернекер... относят эти слова к бреду́,
> брести́. Это объяснение подтверждается примерами типа сумасбро́д,
> первонач. «сошедший с ума»…

Таким образом, слово «сумасброд» (сейчас чаще встречается «сумасбродный» человек) построено путём того же хода мыслей: сойти или сбрести с ума.

И даже слово «бред» (бессмысленная речь), скорее всего, происходит от бродить, т. е. ходить.

Как так получилось, что безумие стало ассоциироваться со схождением или хождением, брожением?

Какова этимология такой метафоры?

Comment: Возможно, будет полезен такой ответ: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24895/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc

Answer (score 2):

Страшная сказка

**Схождение или выхождения из ума**

Ум в данном случае – это правильное логическо-смысловое **пространство** (пространство с правильными связями).

**Наша материя** – удивительная вещь. На определенном уровне она состоит из атомов, которые когда-то представлялись неделимыми, но потом внутри атома выделили элементарные частицы. И что же получилось? Крошечное ядро, и на огромном расстоянии от него находятся электроны – не то частицы, не то уже волны. Основное содержание материи – это **пустота** (тоже на определенном уровне).

Почему же мы видим мир реальных предметов? Нас просто научили его видеть и чувствовать. Если у слепого от рождения человека вдруг появится зрение, то сначала он ничего не увидит.

В чем же тут дело? Есть мнение, что у человека есть так называемая  **«точка сборки».**  Если с ним все нормально, то эта точка сборки постоянная – мы все видим примерно одинаковое пространство, в котором и существуем. Назовем его **«умным» пространством.**

А как **гении**, то есть люди с выдающимися способностями, видят такое пространство? Как знать, может у них "точка сборки" иногда смещается, но они называют это состояние **вдохновением**: "*И мысли в голове волнуются в отваге, И рифмы легкие навстречу им бегут, И пальцы просятся к перу, перо к бумаге. Минута — и стихи свободно потекут*".

Также есть мнение, что нам приходится тратить **немалую энергию** на поддержание этого пространства в порядке. И вдруг – энергетический кризис,  перерасход ресурсов (стрессы и все такое). Тогда «точка сборки» может сместиться, и вместо умного пространства мы увидим бог знает что – неправильные структуры и связи, низкоэнергетические сущности и т. д.

Если вернуться в «умное пространство» не получится, то говорят, что человек выжил из ума, сошел с ума – другими словами **покинул** стройный логический мир, который видят все люди и который его научили когда-то видеть.

*Не дай мне бог сойти с ума.*
*Нет, легче посох и сума;*
*Нет, легче труд и глад.*
*Не то чтоб разумом моим*
*Я дорожил; не то чтоб с ним*
*Расстаться был не рад:*

*Когда б оставили меня*
*На воле, как бы резво я*
*Пустился в темный лес!*
*Я пел бы в пламенном бреду,*
*Я забывался бы в чаду*
*Нестройных, чудных грез.*

*Да вот беда: сойди с ума,*
*И страшен будешь как чума,*
*Как раз тебя запрут,*
*Посадят на цепь дурака*
*И сквозь решетку как зверка*
*Дразнить тебя придут.*

А. С. Пушкин

Comment: Интересная мысль. Действительно, возможно, имеется ввиду некое сошествие с точки правильного видения мира или такого видения мира, как у остальных «нормальных» людей. Большинство людей считают себя нормальными, и когда они видят человека с другим восприятием мира, считают, что с ним что-то не в порядке, он как бы сошёл с правильной точки «смотрения» на мир.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Ум отражает цельность личности, определённость решений в любой жизненной ситуации, следование избранным принципам. Когда осознание наличия крепкого стержня и собственной точки зрения оставляет человека, наступает блуждание (блуд) — дезориентация в пространстве жизненных проблем. Схождение с прочных позиций, потеря основательности в решениях и действиях, и неспособность вернуться в исходное состояние можно выразить словом *сумасшествие*.